# jquery-slimscroll how to bind and unbind the scroll event

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

I am trying to bind and unbind a scroll event. but i count. any one help me please/

my code :

```
$(container).slimScroll().
bind('slimscroll', function(e, pos){
    if(pos == 'bottom') {
        $.event.trigger('bottomReached');
    }
});

$("#off").click(function () {
    container.slimScroll().off('slimscroll');
});

$("#on").click(function () {
    container.slimScroll().on('slimscroll');
});
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/26/+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(container).slimScroll().removeData('events');
```

Here is the corresponding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/27/).

Comment: Then how to add it back? can you please update in jsfiddle (i added already)

Comment: I gave you the updated jsfiddle in my answer. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for me use dropped down menu event in bootstrap frame work i mean use the dropped down menu and event trigger fir open the setInterval for update the data in the slimscroll should stopped . and working again after dropped down hidden

Events
All dropdown events are fired at the .dropdown-menu’s parent element and have a relatedTarget property, whose value is the toggling anchor element.

Event   Description
show.bs.dropdown    This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
shown.bs.dropdown   This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).
hide.bs.dropdown    This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
hidden.bs.dropdown  This event is fired when the dropdown has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).

please check the link below :

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/